# Spacy does not recognise people names when they contain an apostrophe

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"])
doc = nlp("That had been Megan's plan when she got him dressed earlier.")
labels = [ent.label_ for ent in doc.ents]
entity_text = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents]
print(labels) 
print(entity_text)
```

This returns [ORG] for Megan insetad of [PERSON]. What am I doing wrong? I didn't think a simple apostrophe could throw off the NER model like that.

Comment: I also tried "We went to Applebee's last summer" and "We went to Applebee 's last summer", where Applebee is labeled "ORG" in the first example, and "PERSON" in the second. "That had been Megan 's plan when she got him dressed earlier." returns PERSON because of the added space before the possessive s. That's all quite inconsistent.

Comment: I just tried your code and it returned "PERSON". What version are you using?

Comment: @AnastasiiaIurshina:
That is weird.
My version is the most up-to-date: '3.5.0'

Comment: I updated spacy and re-downloaded the model and now it's ORG too :D Maybe create an issue at spacy's github if it's not already there?

Comment: I will, thank you for trying though! I read that they have difficulties obtaining training data for NER, which makes sense.